# Windows service that will perform certain tasks at the desired time

Tags: c#, windows, service, timer

I have a code that I want to run at certain times of the day. For example 08.00 AM and 06.10 PM. I want to write a windows service for this job. But should I set the tick property of the timer object that I will use to perform the operation one-on-one at this time to 1 second? Does it tire my computer to do a check every second, or is there another way ?

Comment: Any reason you're not just letting Windows Scheduled Tasks run an appropriate program at the times you want stuff to happen?

Comment: A Windows Service is good for an application that needs to be running all the time but, as suggested, if you just want it to act at specific times then a simple Console app invoked by a scheduled task is the way to go. My shop have both and we only use the service for things that need to act at any time, e.g. they monitor a folder for uploaded files.

Comment: Is there a reason for running a batch job as a windows service?  Could a scheduled task be a more reliable approach or is it part of a wider service?

Comment: In fact, these codes will work independently of my program. There is a separate project that I have developed, in this project I take the data and save it in a database. This service will only use some data on this database during certain hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the service is the only way to go, you can set the timer tick to be duration until next timer.

```cs
DateTime nowTime = DateTime.Now;

DateTime scheduledTime = new DateTime(nowTime.Year, nowTime.Month, nowTime.Day, 18, 10, 0, 0); //Specify your scheduled time HH,MM,SS 

DateTime scheduledTime2 = new DateTime(nowTime.Year, nowTime.Month, nowTime.Day, 8, 0, 0, 0);

DateTime nextTime = //*Logic to work out next fire* 

if (nowTime > nextTime)
{
  scheduledTime = scheduledTime.AddDays(1);
}
 
double tickTime = (double)(nextTime - DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds;
timer = new Timer(tickTime);
```

Comment: Thanks for your hand. I'll check out.

Comment: For internal time keeping, you really should favor `DateTime.UtcNow` over `DateTime.Now`.

Comment: The constructor for `scheduledTime` and `scheduledTime2` should include the `DateTimeKind`, e.g. `nowTime.Kind`, otherwise they are `Unspecified`.  In your example this would be `Local` (from `DateTime.Now``).  To avoid any DST side effects, you should use `DateTime.UtcNow`, and likewise its Kind is `Utc`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I solve this problem with Windows Scheduled Task.